# How to get # facebook comments using graph api ajax call

Tags: ajax, facebook, json

```
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.stackoverflow.com';

$.getJSON(url, function(resp) {
  $("p").html('comments = ' + resp.comments);
});
```

This puts the following html in my `<p>`: `comments = undefined`

The return string I'm getting from the call is this:

```
{
   "http://www.thinlinebetween.com/tuesday-quote-of-the-day-jean-ingelow/": {
      "id": "http://www.thinlinebetween.com/tuesday-quote-of-the-day-jean-ingelow/",
      "shares": 2,
      "comments": 1
   }
}
```

Do I need to do something like, `resp."http://www.thinlinebetween.com/tuesday-quote-of-the-day-jean-ingelow/".comments` to get the value? The json that's returned isn't easy to parse. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var postUrl = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
var apiUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + postUrl;

$.getJSON(apiUrl, function(resp) {
  $("p").html('comments = ' + resp[postUrl].comments);
});
```

Need to do `resp["http://www.stackoverflow.com"].comments`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the way,

```
$(function(){ 
        var webUrl = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
        var endpoint = 'https://graph.facebook.com';
        $.getJSON(endpoint,{'ids':webUrl},function(response){
            var comments = response[webUrl].comments;
              $("p").html('comments = ' + comments);
        })
    });
```